# Excel saved with openpyxl can't be opened in another system

Tags: python, openpyxl

we have a reporting system which display some dashboards, and we need to update a data table which has the numbers for the dashboard everyday. The problem is the excel file which is saved with openpyxl can't be opened in the reporting system, Everyday after updating the numbers in the excel file, I need to open the excel file and click "save" button, then upload the excel file to the reporting server, then the numbers in the excel file can be read. if I just upload the excel file to the server without doing anything with the excel file, then the server won't able to read data from it. what can be the problem? my code is:

```
    wb = load_workbook('Datasource_klip.xlsx')
    ws=wb["Day"]
 ws['B%d'%(row_index)]=month
...
wb.save('Datasource_klip.xlsx')
```

Comment: BTW, I am using excel 2013, and I don't want to have big change with my script any more, which means I want to continue to use openpyxl

Comment: This is really vague. If you think there is a bug in openpyxl then please submit a bug on the issue tracker with relevant files and instructions on how to replicate it.

Comment: It might have to do with formulas in your updates. If you input or change formulas using openpyxl, the results won't show until you subsequently open the file in Excel.